# Handling REST Exception

Tags: rest, exception, get, cxf, jax-rs

I'm using a REST service with CXF that does a GET request with an int parameter.

```
@Path("parkingservice")
public interface ParkingService {

    /**
     * @param id
     * @return
     */

   @GET
   @Path("/parkings/{id}/parkingState")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   ParkingState getStatus(@PathParam("id") int id);
}
```

I call my service this way :
http://domain.com:8087/services/rest/parkingservice/parkings/2805/parkingState

When I put a number, it works, but when I put a String, I have this exception :

```
WARNING: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dd"
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.handleParameter(InjectionUtils.java:322)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.createParameterObject(InjectionUtils.java:845)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromUriParam(JAXRSUtils.java:1041)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.createHttpParameterValue(JAXRSUtils.java:733)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:708)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:655)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:238)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:239)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:223)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:203)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:137)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:243)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:168)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "dd"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.PrimitiveUtils.read(PrimitiveUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.handleParameter(InjectionUtils.java:310)
    ... 34 more
```

I'd like to avoid having this exception no matter what type I give..or to find a way to handle this exception with a message like "please provide a good Id"

Thanks a lot

Comment: What ist the HTTP result code? 400?

Answer (score 2):

Add an exception mapper to your rest layer. Code goes something like this :

```
package com.cxf.util;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;


public class CustomExceptionMapper implements
        ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    public CustomExceptionMapper () {
    }

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException arg0) {
        //your logic and return accordingly
        return Response.serverError().build();
    }

}
```

And you if you are using Spring to maintain your service beans and cxf configuration then add this mapper as a bean under `jaxrs:providers` tag, where jaxrs is this : `xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"`

Whenever your application will throw notfoundexception it will go in this class.

Second option is that you can take this parameter as String then parse it in your try catch block. On NumberformatException return 400 status code. Since you have a custom POJO as return, you can take a object of HttpServletResponse from org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext and set status in it. Below is a dummy code:

```
public class RestServiceImpl implements RestService{

@Context
MessageContext context;

public CustomPojo getData(String id){
HttpServletResponse httpResponse  = context.getHttpServletResponse();
  try{

  }catch(NumberFormatException e){
     httpResponse.setStatusCode(400);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below signature for getStatus method, this would work both ways.

```
ParkingState getStatus(@PathParam("id") String id);
```

Comment: I have used String and then parse to int.It works. The question remains to, what if I want to catch exceptions, where can I do it? In the implementation of the method it didn't work..I should do it before but I don't know where or at what level

Comment: Check this http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-basics.html#JAX-RSBasics-Exceptionhandling, personnaly I handle exceptions using mappers in CXF. You can customize it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getStatus(@PathParam("id") int id);` takes integer as an argument and you are trying to pass `String` instead of int, that's why it's throwing an exception of `NumberFormatException`.
You have to handle it,or make a Check is the incoming value is int if not then so a message "please provide a valid input".

Comment: I have surrounded my code in the implementation with try/catch NumberFormatException, but it didn't catch it..I don't know at what level I need to catch it

Comment: can you post your implementation?